# Login from username and password in worksheet Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a login form in Excel VBA that reads the usernames and passwords off of a sheet in the workbook. I have already made a login box with multiple users but I want to be able to enter a new username and password and then login with it without entering more code. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.
This is what I have so far:
[Usernames and passwords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLRmG.png)[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLxYU.png)

Comment: "I want to be able to enter a new username and password and then login with it without entering more code" - I'm not sure if I understand what you want here; are you trying to create a form for users to create a new account from?

Comment: It sounds like you're currently matching usernames and passwords directly inside the VBA code, such as `If username = "johndoe" And password = "hunter2"`. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I am doing. :-)

Comment: Maldred, I am trying to have a login and sign up button. If you click the sign up button, it will take you to a form where the user can enter their details. I then want this to go into a worksheet. I then want to login and do this by the program reading what is in the worksheet, seeing if the entered details match the ones stored in the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use a named range or a table to hold the usernames and passwords then evaluate with

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(Username/Password, Rangename/table, 0)) Then
```

This will evaluate to true when the username or password is found.

If Not IsError(Application.Match(username, Usernamerange, 0)) Then

Comment: Create a named range, called "usernamerange", that has all your usernames listed,  Instead of  if username = :John Doe"...... just use the new line in my answer.  It will check your username variable against all entries in the named range.

Comment: what does the 0 do?

Comment: Fnds the first value that is exactly equal to the lookup_value, yours lookup_value is the username variable.

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub LoopingWorksWell()

Dim c, rng as Range
Dim strUser, strPW as String
Dim shtData as Worksheet, shtEntry as Worksheet
Dim bFound as Boolean

Set shtEntry = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'or wherever they are entering UN/PW
Set shtData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'or whatever sheet contains pws
Set rng = sht.Range("A:A") 'or whatever range contains Users, PWs should be the adjacent column

bFound = False

    strUser = shtEntry.Range("A1") 'or wherever
    strPW = shtEntry.Range("A2") 'or wherever
        For each c in rng
             If strComp(c, strUser, vbTextCompare) = 0 and _
                strComp(c.Offset(0,1), strPW, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                   'Whatever you want your code to do
                bFound = True
                Exit For
             End If
        Next c

    If bFound = False Then MsgBox "Incorrect User Name or Password"

End Sub
```